# Google fonts error in js with bootstrap rails app using chartkick

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I have a rails 4 app using boostrap-sass and chartkick charts. Everything works great local but when I tried to push to heroku I got errors that searching revealed were probably due to js problems. So I opened the developer console for pages in my app and I get the following error ONLY on pages that have chartkick charts.

```
GET http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=%27Lucida+Grande%27,+%27Lucida+Sans+Unicode%27,+Verdana,+Arial,+Helvetica,+sans-serif 400 (Bad Request)
```

The charts are ok in the view even if i don't pass special parameters:

```
    <%= pie_chart Account.spending_by_category_chartkick(current_user) %>
```

And the other chart

```
    <%= column_chart networth_data %>
```

If I remove both from the view, the error goes away in developer console. If I only remove one, the error remains. This is what leads me to think the error has something to do with chartkick but I don't know.

The error link suggest "The requested font families are not available." but I didn't place any special suggestions for fonts to use with chartkick.

Is there a way to better trace this error so I can figure out what to do?

Here is the heroku error which is the same as what I get when I try to precompile assets  that sent me on this chase for reference:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «of», expected punc «;» (line: 29885, col: 15, pos: 861062)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:10623)
    at js_error (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:10842)
    at croak (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:19086)
    at token_error (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:19223)
    at expect_token (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:19446)
    at expect (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:19584)
    at regular_for (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:23361)
    at for_ (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:23316)
    at /private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:21220
    at /private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:19957
    at block_ (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150820-10833-1w252rrjs:2359:24599)new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2359:10623)
js_error ((execjs):2359:10842)
croak ((execjs):2359:19086)
token_error ((execjs):2359:19223)
expect_token ((execjs):2359:19446)
expect ((execjs):2359:19584)
regular_for ((execjs):2359:23361)
for_ ((execjs):2359:23316)
(execjs):2359:21220
(execjs):2359:19957
block_ ((execjs):2359:24599)
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:126:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:286:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

My applicaiton.js

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require chartkick
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out the offending file was the following. Removing it, removed the error. I'll create a bunch of partials to do what this one js file does until I understand it enough to make it work in production.

```
//accounts.js

$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  // var getFieldCount = function() {
  //   var accountType = $('#account_type').val();
  //   return $('.field.' + accountType).size();
  // };

  // Add classes to label each field under its account type for later easy grabbing in jQueries
  var accountFields = {}
  try {
    accountFields = JSON.parse($('#account_fields').val());
  } catch(jsonException) {
    //ignore errors without crashing
  }
  for (var accountType in accountFields) {
    var fields = accountFields[accountType];
    for (field of fields) {
      var field = $('#account_' + field).closest('.field');
      field.addClass(accountType);
    }
  }

  if ($('#edit_account').size() > 0) {
    var showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType = function() {
      $('.field').hide();
      var accountType = $('#account_type').val();
      var fields = accountFields[accountType];
      for (field of fields) {
        var field = $('#account_' + field).closest('.field');
        field.show();
      }
    };
    $('#account_type').change(showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType);
    showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType();
  }

  if ($('#new_account').size() > 0) {
    var showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType = function() {
      $('.field').hide();
      var accountType = $('#account_type').val();
      var fields = accountFields[accountType];
      for (field of fields) {
        var field = $('#account_' + field).closest('.field');
        field.show();
      }
    };
    $('#account_type').change(showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType);
    showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType();

    $("#account_type").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Please Select</option>");
  }

});
```

Comment: I don't think the font error and the precompile assets error are necessarily related. It looks more like you have a stray string "of" in your `application.js` file. Could you remove the charts from the view and precompile the assets, to make sure the problems are not related?

Comment: @Marco Sandrini, Thanks for the suggestion. I removed all charts from every view in the app and recompiled....got the same error on assets:precompile, but no more error in browser developer console. So your intuition is liekly correct that the errors are not related. Yet I'm not sure where to go from here. I've posted my application.js file for reference too now.

Comment: Check also the other JavaScript files in your app (the ones pulled in by `require_tree .`). If those are fine, then you have to remove the 3rd party files from your  `application.js` and add then back the first, try to compile assets, add the second, try to compile assets, etc.... until you find the culprit.

Comment: I removed 3rd party files as suggested and still got js_parse error. Then i removed my accounts.js code so the file is blank...now i can deploy to heroku no problems. I added google charts back and can still deploy to heroku no problems. The google fonts error remains in the developer console but it wasn't the problem keeping me from deploying. Something is array with my code in accounts.js....but any page using that code produces no errors in the developer console.

Comment: That is really odd.... but the JS parser from your browser and the JS parser   used in the precompile asset phase are different, so it may be that the browser can "recover" from an error that instead just breaks the precompile-asset parser. The clue is obviously the "of" word, so I would start looking for it in `accounts.js`

Comment: It's probably poorly written js in my account.js file. There are many 'of' lines in the code. Someone else wrote the code for that file and I don't understand it enough to rewrite it. I'm in the process of studying more about what's appropriate and inappropriate js. In the meantime, i've removed it from my app and successfully moved past the error. Thanks for your help. I'll have to use many partials to do what this one js code did. I added the account.js to my original question so all can see.