# Troubleshooting Heroku ExecJS Program Error for Rails deployment

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a new rails app to heroku. The app works great on my machine and I can pull it from github onto another machine and it works great there too.

But it's a different story when trying to deploy to heroku. I've been searching online for similar errors to the following:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «of», expected punc «;» (line: 29885, col: 15, pos: 861062)
```

Most of the questions I've seen on stackoverflow all have a error clue in the trace. But my trace doesn't give much clue (line 29885...? Unexpected token "of"...where??). I have a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129255/google-fonts-error-in-js-with-bootstrap-rails-app-using-chartkick) where I outlined what I found in the js developer console, but It was leading me in the wrong direction.

All the pages are working great locally.

What are ways to troubleshoot this kind of error beyond the browsers developer console?

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «of», expected punc «;» (line: 29885, col: 15, pos: 861062)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:10623)
    at js_error (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:10842)
    at croak (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:19086)
    at token_error (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:19223)
    at expect_token (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:19446)
    at expect (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:19584)
    at regular_for (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:23361)
    at for_ (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:23316)
    at /private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:21220
    at /private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:19957
    at block_ (/private/var/folders/7g/kc34ywms5j9bb5qgfcr0c7tw0000gn/T/execjs20150822-14064-japh2djs:2359:24599)new JS_Parse_Error ((execjs):2359:10623)
js_error ((execjs):2359:10842)
croak ((execjs):2359:19086)
token_error ((execjs):2359:19223)
expect_token ((execjs):2359:19446)
expect ((execjs):2359:19584)
regular_for ((execjs):2359:23361)
for_ ((execjs):2359:23316)
(execjs):2359:21220
(execjs):2359:19957
block_ ((execjs):2359:24599)
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:39:in `exec'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:21:in `eval'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/execjs-2.6.0/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:46:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:212:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/uglifier-2.7.1/lib/uglifier.rb:179:in `compile'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:52:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:126:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:286:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `yield'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:138:in `block in find'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:223:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:207:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:204:in `stat_directory'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:222:in `stat_tree'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:136:in `find'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:162:in `compile'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-3.3.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
```

Heroku logs are showing me the same information as above.

My application.js file:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap
//= require chartkick
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**UPDATE:**

After removing js related files and trying to deploy one by one, it turns out the offending code is the following (removing it allows me to deploy to heroku without problems....oddly enough, any pages using this code in development produce no js errors in the browser developer console and they function without problems)

```
//assets/javascripts/accounts.js

$(document).on('page:change', function() {
  // var getFieldCount = function() {
  //   var accountType = $('#account_type').val();
  //   return $('.field.' + accountType).size();
  // };

  // Add classes to label each field under its account type for later easy grabbing in jQueries
  var accountFields = {}
  try {
    accountFields = JSON.parse($('#account_fields').val());
  } catch(jsonException) {
    //ignore errors without crashing
  }
  for (var accountType in accountFields) {
    var fields = accountFields[accountType];
    for (field of fields) {
      var field = $('#account_' + field).closest('.field');
      field.addClass(accountType);
    }
  }

  if ($('#edit_account').size() > 0) {
    var showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType = function() {
      $('.field').hide();
      var accountType = $('#account_type').val();
      var fields = accountFields[accountType];
      for (field of fields) {
        var field = $('#account_' + field).closest('.field');
        field.show();
      }
    };
    $('#account_type').change(showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType);
    showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType();
  }

  if ($('#new_account').size() > 0) {
    var showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType = function() {
      $('.field').hide();
      var accountType = $('#account_type').val();
      var fields = accountFields[accountType];
      for (field of fields) {
        var field = $('#account_' + field).closest('.field');
        field.show();
      }
    };
    $('#account_type').change(showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType);
    showCorrectFieldsPerAccountType();

    $("#account_type").prepend("<option value='' selected='selected'>Please Select</option>");
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the offending script (in your Update) in a JS lint tool such as http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php, you will see an error for the line:

```
for (field of fields) {
```

This line appears to be what is causing your original error:

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «of», expected punc «;» (line: 29885, col: 15, pos: 861062)
```

Comment: Great tool! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Javascript has some problems, It could be from your dynamically generated Javascript files as well. Although the app works in development mode, if there is any Javascript error, it will throw errors at the time of precompiling process while deploying, hence you are getting this error.

A good start to hunt down this issue is to look at your `Javascript console` in the browser and see where there is an error. Any of your JS files could have an error and it is most likely will be visible in your Javascript console in development mode.

Comment: You might be able to identify the file with the error by manipulating the contents of `application.js` (systematically remove files until it compiles).

Comment: @K M, and @steve, thank you for the suggestions. I posted a link in the above question referencing my attempts with the console. Here it is again: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129255/google-fonts-error-in-js-with-bootstrap-rails-app-using-chartkick

Comment: @steve your suggestion (systematically remove files until it compiles) lead to me finding the offending code. I'm still trying to figure out what to change to make this file work with my account.js code. Thanks again for your suggestion. See original post for update.